# Why does the default dictionary in my code keep expanding?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, defaultdict

I have a default dictionary and I run it through a couple of loops to look for certain strings in the dictionary. The loops don't really append anything to the dictionary yet as it turns out, during the loop, new items keep getting appended to the dictionary and the final dictionary ends up bigger than the original one before the loop. 
I've been trying to pinpoint the error forever but now it's late and I have no idea what's causing this!

```
from collections import defaultdict
dummydict = defaultdict(list)    
dummydict['Alex'].append('Naomi and I love hotcakes')
dummydict['Benjamin'].append('Hayley and I hate hotcakes')
part = ['Alex', 'Benjamin', 'Hayley', 'Naomi']
emp = []
for var in dummydict:
    if 'I' in dummydict[var]:
        emp.append(var)
for car in part:
    for key in range(len(dummydict)):
        print('new len', len(dummydict))
        print(key, dummydict)
        if car in dummydict[key]:
            emp.append(car)
print(emp)
print('why are there new values in the dictionary?!', len(dummydict), dummydict)
```

I expect the dictionary to remain unchanged.

Comment: Can you post some print or something? your dict should have 2 keys: Alex and Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing missing keys as in `dummydict[key]` will add those keys to the defaultdict. Note that `key` is an `int`, not the value at that position, as `for key in range(len(dummydict))` iterates indexes, not the dict or its keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
if car in dummydict[key]:
```

`key` being an integer, and your dict being initially filled with only string as keys, this will create a new value in `dummydict` for each `key`.

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#defaultdict-examples):

> When each key is encountered for the first time, it is not already in the mapping; so an entry is automatically created using the default_factory function which returns an empty list.

For example, this code will show a dummydict with a value in it, because simply accessing `dummydict[key]` will add the key to the dict if that key is not already there.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dummydict = defaultdict(list)    
dummydict[1]

print (dummydict)
```

outputs:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: []})
```

Your issue is that in your loop, you do things like `dummydict[key]` and `dummydict[var]`, which adds those keys.